# All 5 rows combination in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for all 5 rows combinations of a dataframe.
code:

```
from itertools import combinations
for index, row in combinations(df_new.iterrows(), 5):
    input(row)
```

Output what I'm looking for:

```
row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[5]
row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[6]
row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[7]
row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[8]
......................................
row[0], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]
row[0], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[8]
row[0], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[9]
row[0], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[10]
row[0], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[11]
......................................
row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9]
row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[10]
row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[11]
row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[12]
row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[13]
```

dataframe:

```
    index       Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close Close_status
1        1 2018-01-03  172.529999  174.550003  171.960007  172.229996  166.774963          MIN
3        3 2018-01-05  173.440002  175.369995  173.050003  175.000000  169.457214          MAX
6        6 2018-01-10  173.160004  174.300003  173.000000  174.289993  168.769714          MIN
```

Comment: This needs more clarity. Can you share `df_new`.

Comment: I add 3 rows @PacketLoss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
for row in combinations(df_new.values, 5):
    input(row)
```